# sql - using parameters in a in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a simple script in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
Declare @total varchar (max)
set @total = 1

Declare @total2 varchar (max)
set @total2 = '1,4'

if @total in (@total2)
print 'Success'
```

For some reason I cannot get this simple script to work. It will work when I do this though "if 1 in ('1,2')" it will print "Success" Any help[ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will it let you do `set @total2 = ('1, 4')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Dynamic SQL` because your `@total` contains varchar not numbers

```
Declare @total varchar (max)
set @total = 1

Declare @total2 varchar (max)
set @total2 = '1,4'

exec ('if '+@total+' in ('+@total2+') print ''Success'' ' )
```

Comment: try changing `set @total2 = '1,4'` to `Set @total2='1=2 select 5; drop YourFavoriteTableHere;--'`

Comment: @KM. so he can use `Quotename` to Avoid SQL injection

Comment: @Ganesh how could I set a parameter value in dynamic sql example:
exec ('if '+@total+' in ('+@total2+') set '+@total3+' = ''hello'' ' )

Answer (score 0):

`IN` works against sets, not strings.   You could either declare a table variable and perform `INSERT` statements:

```
Declare @total varchar (max)
set @total = 1

Declare @total2 TABLE varchar (max)
(
  total int
)
INSERT INTO @total2 VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @total2 VALUES (4)

if @total in (SELECT total FROM @total2)
print 'Success'
```

or use string functions like `CHARINDEX`, but then you have to consider partial matches, etc.

You *could* convert a comma-delimited string to a table, but you'd still need to insert the values one-by one using a loop.

Comment: if you use a string split function you can just use `if @total in (select SplitValue from dbo.YourSplitFunction(@total2))`  just web search for `sql server split string table function`

Comment: Why would you need a loop if you split the string?

Comment: Here is a great article about splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings